# Stop! Futo Time! Trophy / Achievement

Tags: achievements, mini-ninjas

I complete the game and this trophy did not pop.  I'm wondering if I can just go back to each level on a replay, kill something with Futo, and then exit.  Will that count towards getting a kill in each level with him? I know some of the other trophies (e.g. free all animals) can be glitchy and replay may not work.

Trying to avoid a second play through of this, although I enjoyed the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this trophy guide](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/mini-ninjas/22653-mini-ninjas-road-map-trophy-guide.html), it's possible to do it on a single missed level via level select and it should pop, but he did mention he missed it only on one level so it might not work if you missed it on multiple levels.

If you do want to try it via level select, I would suggest playing the level to it's end just to be sure, or at least until a save point.

Comment: Confirmed. It turns out I only needed one zone as well. Reloading worked for that. I'd have to assume it works if you need multiple levels as well. Also I didn't have to finish the level. As soon as Futo attacked I saw the save icon begin and the trophy popped just after.